# Run As JUnit - ClassNotFoundException - BuildCommand Fix causes class resolution problems

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Here's my Setup:

Eclipse Oxygen

Building and Deploying with Maven 3.3 which includes these specific dependencies for Unit Testing:

- JUnit 4.4
- Mockito 1.9.5

I've created a JUnit test class and added it to ($project/src/test/java).
I added this folder as a source folder and then did a Run As JUnit.

I recieve the following error:

```
Class not found 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

I can fix this by adding the following to the .project file Build Spec:

```
   <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Unfortunately this seems to cause multiple errors to show up under markers for Java Server Faces, etc.

Is this really my fix or could I be missing something else?  It's especialloy frustrating when you have a clean workspace before making this change to fix the "Junit" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These extra dependencies need to be added to the pom.xml

```
<!-- JSF(MyFaces & Tomahawk) Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

The actual jar files can be added as an external library as well, but that would need to be done each time you create a project.